# How do you remove a label with code in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

i have created a label and i want to remove it in another function. what would be the code for this?

Answer (score 10):

The name of the label variable and then removeFromSuperview()

```
label.removeFromSuperview()
```

that will remove it from whatever view it is a part of

[Link to the apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview)